# CharsetDecoder not working on linux machine

Tags: java, linux, character, decoder

Following does not work on linux machine.

```
        Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();

        try {
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("hi.txt");
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fo);
            String msgBody = "ÃŽÂ£YMMETOXH";
            ps.println(decoder.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(decoder.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(msgBody.getBytes())).toString().getBytes())));
            ps.close();
            fo.close();
        } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This code works on windows. What can be the issue? On linux machine decoder does not decode the string.

Comment: Does it throw some kind of exception? Does it print garbage into the file? Also, your file name is quite Windows-specific, although I'm sure Linux is able to create a file with such a convoluted name in your current directory.

Comment: It doesn't throw any exceptions. It creates a file and write same thing as in `msgBody` variable instead of decoded string of `msgBody`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `String.getBytes()` at least once, possibly twice (your enormously long line is hard to read; using several statements would make it easier to understand). That doesn't specify an encoding, so it'll use the platform default encoding. At that point, you've got a platform dependency... hence the problem.

It's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve, but if you're looking for reasons for platform-specific behaviour, that's the first thing to look at.

Oh, and creating a `PrintStream` like that will have the same issue... create an `OutputStreamWriter` with a specific encoding instead.

Comment: Provided "UTF-8" in getBytes() but still faces the same issue.

Comment: @HarryJoy: It's not clear what you mean by "the same issue" as you haven't explained what you're trying to do vs what's actually happening. Note my bit about using `PrintStream` by the way. There's *lots* of encoding and decoding going on in your code - the problem could be in any of them (or multiple).

Comment: I'm trying to decode greek word and save them in a file. I'm getting greek word as `ÃŽÂ£YMMETOXH` in my servlet. When I decode it by above code it remains the same on linux machine but on windows it works fine. I also tried with `OutputStreamWriter`. This also doesn't work.

Comment: @HarryJoy: It sounds like your servlet is receiving the text incorrectly to start with - as far as I'm aware, "£" isn't a valid character in a Greek word... I wouldn't be surprised if the problem was that the code on Windows is *coincidentally* making two errors which cancel each other out.

Comment: I'm entering the greek word as `ΣΥΜΜΕΤΟΧΗ`

Comment: @HarryJoy: Into the web page? Right. Now work out *exactly* how that's going to be transmitted in the web request, and make sure that you can decode that correctly in the servlet. Once you've *received* it correctly, then you can work out how to save it. It's really important that you tackle one conversion at a time.

Comment: can you tell me which encoding will it take on windows when I do getBytes() without argument.

Comment: @HarryJoy: See `Charset.defaultCharset` - but you shouldn't just try to make your Linux box use the same encoding as the Windows box. You should work out *where* things are going wrong. It's not clear to me that you've mapped out each stage in the conversion process, and worked out what encoding should be used at each stage.